# Angular 5 remove child component from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to remove one of the child components from its parent when the user clicks on the close button present in the child component.
I have 3 components in my parent component.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-map></app-map>
<app-rules *ngIf="selectedId"></app-rules>
```

I tried to update the value of selectedId to undefined on click of a close button inside . but it is not taking the updated value and closing the component.

Comment: you need to post more code. You should be bubbling an event from the child component to the parent so that the parent may set your selectedId so if statement will work. There is other ways to share data between components but event bubbling is the cleanest.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was trying to set selectedId value in child component itself and it was not working before.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that *ngIf expects a boolean state. undefined is an invalid state when you validate a number. You have to implement a comparison then e.g.

```
// selectedId is a number
<app-rules *ngIf="selectedId > 0"></app-rules>
```

or

```
// selectedId is a string
<app-rules *ngIf="selectedId !== undefined"></app-rules>

// in case of a string this is also possible
<app-rules *ngIf="selectedId"></app-rules>
```